# How to paginate search with YouTube Data Api on Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, youtube-data-api

I need to analyze all id's from search and in order 50 maxResults is not relevant for me, im trying to increase number of retrieved data by pagination. I want to understand how to do that.

Here is how my code look like:

```
api_key = "***************"

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey = api_key)
print(type(youtube))

request = youtube.search().list(
    q='my unique search query',
    part='id',
    maxResults=50,
    order="viewCount",
    pageToken="CAoQAA",
    type='video')


print(type(request))
res = request.execute()
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
pp = PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(res)
```

Comment: Just to make sure that you know, 50 is the max value for [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#maxResults). Furthermore [this documentation about pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) may help you, if it doesn't, please precise your question.

Comment: yeah, Benjamin! - I know that 50 is the max value for maxResults per page, so I'm trying to make a loop that will repeat a command and scrape every next page till the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation about pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination), you need to loop your requests to YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint by providing as [`pageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageToken) the retrieved [`nextPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#nextPageToken) if there is any. So your code becomes:

```
api_key = "***************"

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey = api_key)
print(type(youtube))

pp = PrettyPrinter()
nextPageToken = ''

while True:
    request = youtube.search().list(
        q='my unique search query',
        part='id',
        maxResults=50,
        order="viewCount",
        pageToken=nextPageToken,
        type='video')
    
    print(type(request))
    res = request.execute()
    pp.pprint(res)
    
    if 'nextPageToken' in res:
        nextPageToken = res['nextPageToken']
    else:
        break
```